# How to use log() transformation in a dataframe list and perform aov()?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, transform, lapply

I hope someone can help me. I am trying to transform my `Weight` and `Height` data to follow a normal distribution and perform anova with it in each data frame. However, I cannot append a new column to the original dataframe with the transformed values. The `Person` and `Age` factors are important in the analysis.

I have this data

```
df_list <- list(
  `1.3.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,  ~Age, 
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,    15,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,  17,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,   19,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,    22,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,  21,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,    20

    ),
  `2.2.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,   ~Age,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,     18,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,   18,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,    19,
       "Alex",    175L,     75L,    25,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,   27,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,    26
    ), 
  `1.1.B` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,    ~Age,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,       22,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,     23,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,      25, 
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,       27,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,     18,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,      19   
    )
)
```

Failed attempts are:

```
russia <- lapply(df_list, (function(x) log10(Age)))
```

```
greece <- function(df){ 
  mutate(df, transformed_Age = log10(df$Age)) 
}

spain <- lapply(df_list, greece)
View(spain)
```

```
arkansas <- df_list
canada <- function(df){ 
    log10(as.numeric(df$Age))
}

arkansas <- lapply(df_list, canada)
View(arkansas)
```

I would also like to try other transformations so I hope someone can enlighten me how I can do that. I tried boxcox transformation but failed.

Comment: You could just apply the log in the formula passed to `aov`, e.g., `aov(log(y) ~ x, data = DF)` is perfectly valid code. There is no need to change the data.

Comment: @Roland I tried this solution but gave me an error because my control group has a value of 0.

Comment: Why are you taking the log of a variable that can be zero? You should probably consult a statistician for better approaches.

Comment: @Roland I agree, I am just trying this out in order to learn R while trying to analyze my data. But surely I will consult a statistician

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
cols <- c('Height', 'Weight')
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {x[cols] <- log10(x[cols]);x})
df_list

#$`1.3.A`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Person Height Weight   Age
#  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Alex     2.24   1.88    15
#2 Gerard   2.26   1.93    17
#3 Clyde    2.25   1.90    19
#4 Alex     2.24   1.88    22
#5 Gerard   2.26   1.93    21
#6 Clyde    2.25   1.90    20

#$`2.2.A`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Person Height Weight   Age
#  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Alex     2.24   1.88    18
#2 Gerard   2.26   1.93    18
#3 Clyde    2.25   1.90    19
#4 Alex     2.24   1.88    25
#5 Gerard   2.26   1.93    27
#6 Clyde    2.25   1.90    26

#$`1.1.B`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Person Height Weight   Age
#  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Alex     2.24   1.88    22
#2 Gerard   2.26   1.93    23
#3 Clyde    2.25   1.90    25
#4 Alex     2.24   1.88    27
#5 Gerard   2.26   1.93    18
#6 Clyde    2.25   1.90    19
```

If you want to keep the original columns as it is and create new columns with transformed values

```
cols <- c('Height', 'Weight')
new_cols <- paste0('new_', cols)
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {x[new_cols] <- log10(x[cols]);x})
df_list
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I tried both solutions but it returned only the transformed data instead of appending a new column to the existing dataframe. also the output is not a dataframe. I also want to retain other columns such as the `Person` and `Age` columns

Comment: The second solution (with `new_cols`) returns new columns retaining all the original columns. Have you tried that ? It works for me.

Comment: It did worked! i might have mixed something up that is why it did not worked the first time. I would like to ask, how to can I handle `-inf` after log transformation?

Comment: How do you want to handle them? If you have 0 values in the data it would return `-Inf` because `log10(0)` returns `-Inf`. If you want to turn them back to 0 you can use`{x[new_cols] <- log10(x[cols]);x[new_cols][x[new_cols] == '-Inf'] <- 0;x}`

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much. Now that I have transformed the data, I can now perform aov(). I'm new to data science and this is very big help. Based on your expertise, is it ok to return 0 values to 0 and perform anova or is this incorrect since I have transformed the independent variable using log transformation?

Comment: I'm not a stats expert so I'll prefer not to comment on that.

Comment: @TylerRuddenfort No that's not okay. E.g., `log(0.1)` is already a negative value. If you replace `-Inf` with 0, you are even changing the ranks of your values!

Comment: @Roland thanks for this input. Didn't know that! I'll forward this to a statistician, but for the sake of learning R, I'll continue to play around codes and the syntax. thanks again